# Why does React not allow you to bind an event to a function?

Tags: reactjs

My code below gives me the error similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495363/in-react-why-do-i-have-to-bind-an-onclick-function-rather-then-calling-it):

> "Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state."

```
class BookList extends React.Component
{
    removeBook(bookName)
    {
        Actions.UpdateBooks();
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <TextField defaultValue={this.book.name}  />
            <i  onClick={this.removeBook(this.book.name)} />
        );
    }
}
```

Makes sense - the function is called every time render occurs.

So I changed the binding to

```
onClick={function() {this.removeBook(book.name);}
```

and now the method is **never** called when I click.  Why?

Comment: I found that arrow functions and rebinding this as per the answers below still didn't work. I also had to wrap <i> in <span onclick> otherwise React wasn't adding the event to <i>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), because now you call function

```
this.removeBook.bind(this, book.name);
```

about second case

```
onClick={function() {this.removeBook(book.name);}
```

`this` in this case will be `window` in `window` there is not function `removeBook` that's why you don't get any result(`window.removeBook === undefined`)., if you use ES6 you can use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
onClick={() => this.removeBook(book.name) }
```

in this case `this` refers to parent scope

Answer (score 1):

You're using es6 classes, so automatic binding isn't working: You could use arrow functions (w/ lexical this) like so:

```
<i onClick={() => this.removeBook(this.book.name)} />
```